# remove single link from HTTPS in my .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I am forcing the entire site to run via `HTTPS`. I then follow up with forcing `www` and processing pages through `index.php` with the following in my `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"https"' [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]
</IfModule>
```

Then below that a ways...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Redirect non-www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:proto}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My issue is that I need to allow pages that come in with say `PRD` in the `URI` to go through `HTTP` and NOT `HTTPS`.

So http://www.localsite.com/index.php?PRD=123

Would not go to https while every other link would.

---

*** EDIT ***

---

I'll try to clarify a bit more. I tried to catch the redirect/rewrite before any others, but it still loops between the following:
`http://www.local.com/index.php?PRD=123`
`https://www.local.com/index.php?PRD=123`

This tells me that it IS catching it, but for some reason the second set of rules are redirecting still too.

I placed the following (I'm leaving other attempts commented out in case they are better?) above the first two, turned on the engine, and moved the Options in with this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PRD=([0-9]+) [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    #RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have also tried placing everything in one block using this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    #Redirect non-www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.local.com/$1 [L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

    #Redirect singular segments first
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PRD=([0-9]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.local.com/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: it is not completely clear which url you want to pass please provide example.

Comment: Updated the op to contain link example. The entire site is forced https. I want to add the exception for links with that querystring and numeric value.

Comment: You have shown 2 blocks of rules but it is not clear which one is in use. Can you show your full working .htaccess in question

Comment: Those are the only two `mod_rewrite` segments in the `.htaccess` file. They fall in the order I have them above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use rewrite condition for query string where you are setting the https redirection, try with below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^PRD=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I've tried that and others, but it gets stuck in a redirect loop from http to https and back

Comment: You may have to reconsider `^(.*)$` because it matches all the patterns try with ^ caret only.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I am not understanding where. I ended up using the `proto` variables because sometimes CloudFare was interfering and sometimes it wasn't. This seemed to catch them all. Sadly, I am not as proficient with `.htaccess` as I should be.I updated the OP to reflect a couple of the lines I have tried. I figured if I caught it before the others then it would redirect and be fine. That doesn't seem to be the case though.

Comment: After seeing your new rule I am unable to see any R flag.

Comment: Your code doesn't properly route the main pages removing `index.php` from the URL so the site "breaks". It also still goes directly to `https://www.local.com/index.php?PRD=123`.   :(